# Possibility of turning a Chromebook to a NAS system?

Tags: nas, google-chrome-os

Recently, I have received a ~$300 Chromebook for free, however it's barely useable for my daily routine. *[Lenovo 100e specs.](https://www.cnet.com/products/lenovo-100e-chromebook/)*

Always wanted a network drive for backup and family storage, so I was thinking about converting it to a NAS system. However, after some researching, I haven't notice anyone talking about building NAS with a Chromebook on ChromeOS.

My requirements aren't high, or at least I don't think they are (it's my first time trying it):

- 4~8TB RAID1 (ideally)
- ~150MB/s Read
- >50MB/s Write
- It is for personal/family use, so downtimes/weekly maintenance are fine(as long it's not too difficult)
- Power wattage wouldn't be a problem since I don't pay for electric, plus they seem to use low wattage anyways

It has 2 USB-A 3.0 port, and 1 USB-C data port.

---

#### My question:

- Is it possibly to do them within ChromeOS without too much digging around? (I don't mind using Debian inside ChromeOS)
- Should I just install a different system them was purposed for NAS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any computer as a NAS. NAS software doesn't really use much processing power, so a Chromebook should work just fine. You do need to use another software, or at least a VM inside the ChromeOS. FreeNAS is a good free option, centOS is a good Linux distro, but it will not be as easy as just running freeNAS. Your read and write speeds will be limited by the USB interface, unless you stick a massive SSD or 2.5" HDD in your Chromebook.

So to summarize, yes you can do it, yes you need some sort of third party software, either installed dual boot on the system, or running in a VM, or just as the only option.